# Compiler Optimization for methods that only call another method

Tags: c#, optimization, methods, compiler-construction, il

I think my question is best asked with an example

```
Method1(variable var1, variable var2)
{
    Method2([null or default value goes here], var1, var2)
}

Method2(variable newvar, variable var1, variable var2)
{
    //functionality
}
```

Would the compiler optimise our code by changing all calls to method1 to a call to method 2? I would think that it would inline the method. However, what if method2 calls 3 which calls 4 which calls 5 which calls 6? Does the compiler change method1 calls to a call to method 6 with the values that it will have?

Comment: Keep in mind that inlining `Method1` (or `Method2` for that matter) saves practically *no* time unless 1) `//functionality` is almost nothing, and 2) it is called often enough that it accounts for a good percentage of time. So if/when the compiler/JITter inlines it, it does so only because in some circumstances it might help.

Comment: Why do you care? Surely there are more important things to worry about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is completely an implementation detail, and subject to change.  However, the CLR team has [blogged about when methods are eligible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2004/11/01/250398.aspx) to be inlined (though this is, of course, pre-RyuJIT).

Note that the C# compiler doesn't ever inline the methods - the inlining happens during the JIT compilation phase.  In general, a simple method call, as you described, (without virtual/abstract methods being used) will get inlined at runtime, however.